# How to parse out JavaScript from arbitrary HTML

Tags: java, jericho-html-parser

I'm using jericho for sanitizing html and it works great. Except in one situation I can't figure out.  I want to completely remove any script and the script content. Right now I'm getting the script tag removed but the actual script content is kept.

So currently I create a Source object and do a fullSequentialParse. Then I create an OutputDocument and loop through each tag.

When I get to a "script" tag I just want to replace the whole thing with "".

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Jericho, however it has the capability to work on a tree, very similar to a DOM tree, so you can remove the `script` *element* instead of just the *tag*. (If you have a huge HTML, this may not be optimal, though).

If not, then you can go for the SAX way of things. Remember the opening `script` tag, and when you reach the closing tag, you can remove everything inbetween.

Answer (score -1):

Simple and efficient method -

1. Do the traversal to reach script Tags one by one.
2. For every script Tag you can get its next end Tag (use a for loop).
3. Get positions(Integer value) of start Tag and end Tag.
4. Remove those lines from your source object.
5. Replace the source file. (just create a new file and save in same folder, it'll overwrite)

**A2A** **:)**